# How to make a recursive function for find all Euler path in a graph?

Tags: java, algorithm, recursion, graph

I'm trying to find all Euler paths in a graph. For doing this, I'm using a java code based on this: http://www.sanfoundry.com/java-program-implement-euler-circuit-problem/ (this example finds just one euler path).

Basically, I made some changes in PrintEulerUtil method (below), but that brings me some problems in the algorithm, and I can't find a solution that works.

Here is the code:

```
public void printEulerTourUtil(int vertex, int[][] adjacencyMatrix, String trail) {

        // variable that stores (in every recursive call) the values of the adj matrix
        int[][] localAdjacencyMatrix = new int[this.numberOfNodes + 1][this.numberOfNodes + 1];
        // verifies if there is some edge unvisited. if not, then the euler path is in variable "trail"
        int verificationSum = 0;

        // copy values of variable, not only reference
        for (int i = 0; i <= numberOfNodes; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j <= numberOfNodes; j++) {
                localAdjacencyMatrix[i][j] = adjacencyMatrix[i][j];
                verificationSum += localAdjacencyMatrix[i][j];
            }
        }

        Integer destination = 1;

        // if verificationSum != 0, then, at least one edge is in the adj matrix
        if (verificationSum != 0) {
           // test for every destination possible if is valid (isValidNextEdge) and if has connection between the actual vertex and the destination.
            for (destination = 1; destination <= numberOfNodes; destination++) {
                if (localAdjacencyMatrix[vertex][destination] == 1 && isValidNextEdge(vertex, destination, localAdjacencyMatrix)) {
                    // remove the edge for the next recursion call (and not loop the program)
                    removeEdge(vertex, destination, localAdjacencyMatrix);
                    trail = trail.concat(destination.toString());
                    // recursive call 
                    printEulerTourUtil(destination, localAdjacencyMatrix, trail);
                }
            }
        } else {
            System.out.println("Euler path: " + trail);
        }
    }
```

The problem is: when the recursive call returns, and destination increments, the graph (adjacency matrix) suffers some changes that impossible to find new (nexts) Euler paths. It easier with an example, so:

[image]

As you can see, for example, in the second level of the three, when destination is equals to 4, the edges 1-2 and 1-3 are already removed by previous recursive calls. Then, the graph is not the same of the beggining... which make impossible to find the Euler paths after the first one (because the graph isn't correct).

Any thoughts? If someone wants my entire code, just ask. Any help will be very useful. Thank you so much and sorry the size of the post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have already identified the problem!

> when the recursive call returns, and destination increments, the graph (adjacency matrix) suffers some changes

At the start of the recursive function, you are currently taking a copy of the `adjacencyMatrix` that has been passed in to you. However, you then *corrupt* this local copy as you loop through the possible destination edges. As you have observed, after the return from the recursive call along the *first* destination edge, your `localAdjacencyMatrix` has already been changed - it's no longer correct to pass it to the recursive call for the *second* destination edge.

To resolve your problem, you need to keep better track of the adjacency matrix that was passed *in* to you, and the multiple *different* adjacency matrices you pass down.

I haven't checked this, but I'd say you need to:

- change the test just after `// test for every destination possible if is valid (isValidNextEdge) and if has connection between the actual vertex and the destination` so that it works on `adjacencyMatrix`, the invariant matrix that was passed in
- copy the code that copies values from `adjacencyMatrix` to `localAdjacencyMatrix` to just before `// remove the edge for the next recursion call (and not loop the program)`. This will ensure that when you remove an edge, you do it from a *fresh* copy of the input adjacency matrix

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I was not sure about my conclusion when I wrote this, actually :) Since yesterday I was thinking a lot and finally got a right recursive method for this problem. Your answer help me a lot! Thanks!